# Swiper js slide width on small screen is too big

Tags: swiper.js

Hellp Im using Swiper@11.0.5
on screens that is  > 575 is works fine but on smaller screens the swiper-wrapper and swiper-container are 0 
and the swiper-slide width is soo big:    width: 4.48921e6px; 
the website: https://mav.greecegoldenvisa.com/

js code:

```
 const swiper = new Swiper('.icon-card-swiper', {
      speed: 5000,
      spaceBetween: 20,
      slidesPerView: 3,
      loop: true,
      navigation: {
        nextEl: '.swiper-next',
        prevEl: '.swiper-prev',
      },
      breakpoints: {
        // when window width is >= 0px
        0: {
          slidesPerView: 1,
          spaceBetween: 0
        },
        // when window width is >= 768px
        768: {
          slidesPerView: 2,
          spaceBetween: 20
        },
        // when window width is >= 1024px
        1024: {
          slidesPerView: 3,
          spaceBetween: 20
        }
      }
    });
```

css code:

```
   .swiper-slide{
        height: auto;
        border-radius: 16px; 
        overflow: hidden;
    }
```

html code:

```
<section class="icon-card-slider mb-100">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <!-- Slider -->
            <div class="col-12">
                <div class="icon-card-swiper swiper-container">
                    <div class="swiper-wrapper">
                        <?php foreach ($cards as $card) : ?>
                            <div class="swiper-slide">
                                <a href="<?= $card['url'] ?>" class="icon-card" aria-label="<?= $card['title'] ?>">
                                    <div class="icon">
                                        <?= file_get_contents($card['icon']) ?>
                                    </div>
                                    <h3 class="heading-3"><?= $card['title'] ?></h3>
                                    <div class="theme-des"><?= $card['description'] ?></div>
                                </a>
                            </div>
                        <?php endforeach; ?>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Post code using `{}` formatting (fifth button from left).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. It's due to the Swiper consistently **changing the width inside a flex container.**

I fixed it by passing width explicitly to the parent container like

```css
.col-12 {
  width: 100%;
}

.col-6 {
  width: 50%;
}

// Or 
.col-6 {
  width: 100%;
  flex: 0 0 50%;
}
```

Tell me if this resolves the issue.